# Getting UTF8 strings directly from the web service call without conversion to String

Tags: java, string, web-services, cxf

I'm using CXF to implement a web services server.
Since I'm low on memory I don't want the web service call parameters to be translated strings which are UTF-16 I rather access the original UTF-8 buffers which are usually half in size in my case.
So if I have a web method:

```
void addBook(String bookText)
```

How can I get the bookText without CXF translating it to java string?

Comment: Then you need to accept something different from a String, e.g. a stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML parsers used in Java (StAX parsers for CXF) only allow getting the XML contents as either a String or char[].   Thus, it wouldn't be possible to get the raw bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `String` object in java, there is no such thing as whether it is UTF-8 or UTF-16 string. The encoding comes in when you convert a `String` to or from a byte array.

A `String` in java is a character array. If you already have a `String` object in java (for example passed as a parameter to your `addBook()` method, it has already been interpreted properly and converted to a character array.

If you want to avoid character encoding conversions, the only way to do that is to define your method to receive a byte array instead of a `String`:

```
void addBook(byte[] bookTextUtf16);
```

But keep in mind that in this way you have to "remember" the encoding in which the byte array is valid (adding it to the name is one way).

If you need a `java.lang.String` object, then there is nothing you can do. A `String` is a character array, characters with which each being a 16-bit value. This is `String` internal, no way to change the internal representation. Either accept this or don't use `java.lang.String` to represent your strings.

An alternative way could be to create your own `Text` class for example which honds the UTF-8 encoded byte array for example, and as long as you don't need the `String` representation, keep it as a byte array and store it if you want to. Only create the `java.lang.String` instance when you do need the `String`.

Comment: This is exactly my problem. I'm asking if there is a way to get the raw byte array the client sent which is half in memory. I don't need or want this converted String object.

Comment: But I still want my clients to see it as a UTF-8 input string and not as a byte array. @icza

Comment: As said in my answer, there is no such thing as UTF-8 String in Java. `String` is a character array. There is only UTF-8 encoded byte array for a String.

Comment: My web service clients use UTF-8 encoding. But if you don't do anything special CXF will translate them to regular java string which is UTF-16 (which is two bytes per character).